# Android "Drag and Drop Shadow" and a View position, scale and rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-view

everyone. I do have two questions that I cannot solve. I made two videos to help understanding:
(a) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZG-wh6_69A

(b) https://youtu.be/3Wr9IOPihN0

This is my first android app, so I don't know if I'm doing the right way.

1. **View scale and rotate (draw line and curve it).**

I have two types of objects to make changes: vector drawables (are xml files) and a line that's draw at run time. I don't think that vector drawables are wrong in this issue, just the line. Those elements are a View inflated with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/element_generic_root"
    android:background="#0000ff">
    <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent">-->

    <!-- generic android:src just to show on xml preview. -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/element_generic_image"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/element_generic_resize"
        android:background="@drawable/button_resize"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/element_generic_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/element_generic_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/element_generic_rotate"
        android:background="@drawable/rotate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/element_generic_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/element_generic_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On ImageView that everything happens (drawing the line and the vectors drawables). **Ok, now I will explain the first problem.**

When resizing/rotating vectors drawables, there's no problem to fix the pivot in (0, 0). But there is with lines, because when rotating it's more confortable for the user to see the rotation relative to the middle (see the video (a)). And I've got a problem doing this, the line element change its position when doing resize (i don't know why). My resize code is:

```
public void resize() {
        float scale = moveResize / DEFAULT_WIDTH;
        float height = scale * DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

        float nw = moveResize < MIN_WIDTH ? MIN_WIDTH : moveResize;
        float nh = height < MIN_HEIGHT ? MIN_HEIGHT : height;

        double rad = Math.toRadians(getView().getRotation());
        double cos = Math.cos(rad);
        double sin = Math.sin(rad);

        double difh = (nh - getHeight()) * cos;
        double difw = (nw - getWidth()) * sin;

        setWidth(nw);
        setHeight(nh);

        if(nh == MIN_HEIGHT) difw = 0;

        getView().setX((float) (getView().getX() + (difw / 2)));
        getView().setY((float) (getView().getY() - (difh / 2)));

        build();
    }
```

2. **Drag Shadow Builder**

I'm not getting a way to create the shadow on the exactly position of the element and on the drop event, put the element exactly where the shadow is. Here's my shadow code:

```
public class ElementDragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public ElementDragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);

        double rotationRad = Math.toRadians(getView().getRotation());

        int w = (int) (getView().getWidth() * getView().getScaleX());
        int h = (int) (getView().getHeight() * getView().getScaleY());

        double s = Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad));
        double c = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad));

        width = (int) (w * c + h * s);
        height = (int) (w * s + h * c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(getView().getScaleX(), getView().getScaleY(), width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.rotate(getView().getRotation(), width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.translate((width - getView().getWidth()) / 2, (height - getView().getHeight()) / 2);

        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set(shadowSize.x / 2, shadowSize.y / 2);
//        shadowTouchPoint.set(shadowSize.x, shadowSize.y);
    }

}
```

Sorry for the long text, but I'm trying to be most understood as possible.

Thanks in advance,
André Vendramini